# How many automatic voting reversals happen on a daily basis?

Tags: discussion, statistics, serial-voting

Purely out of curiosity and interest, on average, how many automatic voting reversals happen on a daily basis? Is this a metric moderators or CMs can see?

I'm not sure if there's any other situations where voting might be automatically reversed but I'm thinking of the reversals that happen after a serial downvoting (or upvoting!) spree.

Comment: Or upvoting sprees... or voting rings... not all targeted voting is negative. :D It's all against the rules... but not always downvotes.

Comment: @Catija Good point!

Comment: Which site(s) are you asking about?

Comment: @PolyGeo Well mostly I use SO, so I guess that would be a good starting point. Not sure really, I don't know how this statistic would be organised or collected.